# PHP Apache server combine with Python web app

Tags: python, php, apache, plotly-dash

Can I run a python server on the same Apache PHP server in order to use charts etc. that are included in the python dash application?

The implementation now is as follows. Php server uses an iframe in order to depict the python web app that is running in the same ip but on different port, but there is a need to change it for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache as a proxy to an internal server.

Apache server or php interpreter don't use iframes, you're adding html code that the browser will use to embeed the python server provided webpage into an iframe.

You're not doing anything wrong but to me seems error prone.

I would use a new domain to the webpage provided by python and setup his security and certs like any other server/web.

You can add CSP, feature policy, cors policy, frame options, xss protection, strict transport...

It's posible to send a request to the server using php and display back on the webpage the fetched graphs.